# Plotly-Dash not showing list of graph elements

Tags: python, html, arrays, plotly, plotly-dash

If I place `dcc.Graph` elements hardcoded in the layout:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='graph-hammer'),
        dcc.Graph(id='graph-saw'),
        dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=1000, n_intervals=0)]))
```

I get my desired result of 2 graphs plotted without problems.

But if I create a list of `dcc.Graph` elements using `append`:

```
list_graphs = []
for t in tools:
    list_graphs.append(html.Div(dcc.Graph(id='graph-' + t)))

app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        list_graphs,
        dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=1000, n_intervals=0)]))
```

I get a blank screen, with no errors being thrown.

What am I doing wrong when passing the list to the layout?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to add `*` in front of the list. For example:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div([
        *list_graphs,
        dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=1000, n_intervals=0)]))
```